# When using jQuery with ArcGIS (3.18), execute callback results are empty

Tags: jquery, arcgis, esri

I'm trying to use ArcGIS with jQuery and load in the information via AJAX. A previous version that used XHTTP requests worked, but it did not use jQuery. This version returns empty results in the callback function. Once when I ran it, there was results (the ones I wanted too) in the network response, but the JSON object always seems to return empty.

Here is the callback function:

```
function showResults(results) {
    console.log(results);
    var resultItems = [];
    if(results.features.length == 0) {
      $('.potential-adds').text("No valid addresses");
    } else {
      resultItems.push("<h4>Choose Address:</h4>");
      for(var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
        var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
        resultItems.push("<div><input type=\"radio\" name=\"address\" id=\"add" + i + "\">");
        for(var attr in featureAttributes) {
          if(featureAttributes[attr]) resultItems.push("<label>" + featureAttributes[attr] + "</label>");
        }
        resultItems.push("</div>");
      }
      console.log("Results: " + resultItems.join(""));
      $('.potential-adds').text(resultItems.join(""));
    }
    for(var k = 0; k < results.features.length; k++) {
      $("#add" + k).on("click", function() {
        prepGIS($scope);
      });
    }
  }
```

This was built from ArcGIS' example code for query data without a map:

```
function showResults (results) {
      var resultItems = [];
      var resultCount = results.features.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
        var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
        for (var attr in featureAttributes) {
          resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
        }
        resultItems.push("<br>");
      }
      dom.byId("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");
    }
```

And is using the same execute call demonstrated in the same example:

```
queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
```

Comment: So this is empty `console.log(results);` or undefined?...also can you show us the old xhhtp request and the new version?

Comment: console.log(results); returns a JSON object with results.features an empty array where it's supposed to be putting the information. The request is working, it's returning with a 200 status. The original showResults is the one on bottom from the original question.

Comment: I mean not the callback functions, but the ajax request

Comment: Well ArcGIS is doing the AJAX call on its own with its QueryTask:

`var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://arcgisprod01/arcgis/rest/services/Accela/XAPO/MapServer/2");
  var query = new Query();
  query.returnGeometry = false;
  query.outFields = ['ADDRESSNUMBER', 'STREETPREFIX', 'STREETNAME', 'STREETSUFFIX', 'STREETTYPE', 'UNIT', 'ZIPCODE', 'ZIPCITY', 'STATE', 'SERVICEAREA', 'PARCELNUMBER'];`